# How to update variable value in sql with in column selection query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to update user variable with column selection. I got error like this

```
SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations
```

I Need like this report: Here credit and debit table columns. Balance is user column

Table value

[image]

Expected Result

[image]
I tried like this code

```
Declare @Openingbalance decimal(18,8) set @Openingbalance=100 select  CreditAmount, DebitAmount, (@Openingbalance + CreditAmount-DebitAmount) as 'Balance' from ACT_Transaction
```

This result is shown wrong. Because opening balance not updated in select statement

Answer (score 2):

This should work for SQL 2008 onwards

```
Declare @Openingbalance decimal(18,8) = 100
select CreditAmount, 
       DebitAmount, 
       (@Openingbalance + CreditAmount-DebitAmount) as 'Balance' 
from ACT_Transaction
```

Comment: yes it's working. but result wrong . did you see my expected result? balance should update next row.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you set the value of the variable to a static 100, then each row will use the same value. From your desired output, I think you are looking for a running total

Comment: yes that opening balance variable should update. because I have opening balance 100. now 100 credited in my account so balance should show 200.after that 10 credit . now balance 210.if debit we need to deduct.

Comment: Search for `Running Totals`. Also, your question needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Openingbalance decimal(18,8) 
set @Openingbalance=100 
select  @Openingbalance as 'Openingbalance', CreditAmount
DebitAmount, (@Openingbalance + CreditAmount-DebitAmount) as 'Balance' from ACT_Transaction
```

Comment: yes it's working. but result wrong . did you see my expected result? balance should update next row

Comment: yes that opening balance variable should update. because I have opening balance 100. now 100 credited in my account so balance should show 200.after that 10 credit . now balance 210.if debit we need to deduct.

Answer (score 0):

technically your query is correct but you didn't mention that you want to display opening balance as seperate column or in balance column?

You Can do Something Like This using sub query

Declare @optBal Numeric(10)
Set @optBal=100

select  fldDate,
fldTrxType,
fldAmount,
(select sum(convert(money, case when cramt then -1 else 1 end) * cramt + @optBal) 
from tblTrx 
where fldDate <= trx.fldDate) as Balance
from    tblTrx trx
order by fldDate

Comment: opening balance variable should update. because I have opening balance 100. now 100 credited in my account so balance should show 200.after that 10 credit . now balance 210.if debit we need to deduct. see my output